# pandas : How to get groups of each n rows after row matching query?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

Let's say I have this pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.randint(-10, 10, size=100),
                   'y': np.random.randint(-10, 10, size=100)})
```

And I have any query that selects rows, e.g.

```
query = (df['x'] > 3) & (df['y'] < 0)
```

How do I get groups of the rows that match this query AND the next successive k rows (if there's less than k, then return however many are available)?

For example, for `k = 2`, a cumbersome and manual way to do it is:

```
# 1st value
sel0 = df[query].reset_index()

# 2nd value
sel1 = df[query.shift(1).fillna(False)].reset_index()

# 3rd value
sel2 = df[query.shift(2).fillna(False)].reset_index()

concat_df = pd.concat([sel0, sel1, sel2])
grouped_df = concat_df.groupby(concat_df.index)
groups = [grouped_df.get_group(i) for i in grouped_df.groups]
```

Is there a one-liner that can generalize this to any `k` and execute it fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this using `cumsum`, `groupby` and `head`:

Try this, where k=2 use head(3), current record plus two:

```
df.groupby(query.cumsum()).head(3)
```

and to generalize try this

```
k=2
df.groupby(query.cumsum()).head(k+1)
```

Comment: Good idea, that reduces my current solution to `grouped_df = df.groupby(query.cumsum())` and `groups = [grouped_df.get_group(i).head(k+1) for i in grouped_df.groups]`. I upvoted your answer, will select it if no one comes up with a faster solution.

Comment: You might speed up the code a bit by doing this `g = df.groupby(query.cumsum())` and `groups = [i[:3] for _, i in g]`